# CSS hover after not working on images?

Tags: css, hover, pseudo-element

I have made a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ATdRD/

Can anyone fix this or spot why this isn't working??

When the user hovers over the image I'd like for the data-title to appear for which i can style like a tooltip

Comment: @JasonGennaro When the user hovers over the image for the data-title to appear for which i can style like a tooltip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works if you wrap it in a `p` tag and give it some positioning:

```
<p class="kudoIcon" data-title="Admin">
    <img src="http://www.google.co.uk/images/srpr/logo3w.png" alt="Wapple" />
</p>
```

**CSS**

```
.kudoIcon {
    position: relative;
}

.kudoIcon:hover:after{
    content: attr(data-title);
    position: absolute;
    top:100px;          /*ADDED*/
    left:100px;         /*ADDED*/
    white-space: nowrap;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85);
    padding: 3px 7px;
    color: #FFF;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    margin-left: 7px;
    margin-top: -3px;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/ATdRD/2/

Semantically, it would probably be better to place it inside a `div` or a `figure` tag, as @BoltClock mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that `:after` on an `<img>` tag simply isn't supported by most browsers. (apparently it is supported by Opera, but not much else)

The best solution I can give you is to either wrap your `<img>` in a `<div>` or similar, and put the `:after` on that, or abandon the `<img>` tag entirely and use a `background-image` instead.

I found this site - http://lildude.co.uk/after-css-property-for-img-tag - which may help you too.

Answer (score 0):

`:after & :before` are not work on `replaced` elements like `img` , `input`, `button`

check this http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/replacedelements

So, you have to define `non-replace` element before `img` tag like this

```
<a href="">
    <img src="image" alt="Wapple" />
</a>
```

http://sixrevisions.com/css/snazzy-hover-effects-using-css/